# DevExpress mvc extension :How to bind a object to DashboardSourceModel in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, dashboard

I am following the loading event of dashboard,but can not able to deploy this in my project.Can anyone help me to find the right approach.

Here is my controller

```
      public ActionResult Demo()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult DemoDashboardViewerPartial()
    {
        return PartialView("_DemoDashboardViewerPartial", DemoDashboardViewerSettings.Model);
    }
    public FileStreamResult DemoDashboardViewerPartialExport()
    {
        return DashboardViewerExtension.Export("DemoDashboardViewer", DemoDashboardViewerSettings.Model);
    }
    class DemoDashboardViewerSettings
    {
        public static DashboardSourceModel Model
        {
            get
            {
                return DashboardSourceModel();
            }
        }

        private static DashboardSourceModel DashboardSourceModel()
        {
            DashboardSourceModel model = new DashboardSourceModel();
            model.DashboardSource = typeof(IDBOWeb.Code.Dashboards.Dashboard1);
            return model;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to add a pie item to dashboard by adding data source through binding the object and passes the arguments and values to pie item.
 Here is my dashboard1.cs:

```
    namespace IDBOWeb.Code.Dashboards
  {
    public partial class Dashboard1 : DevExpress.DashboardCommon.Dashboard
    {
    public Dashboard1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void Dashboard1_DashboardLoading(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
        var data = new suggestReport().GetData();
        dashboard.AddDataSource("Data Source 1",data);

        PieDashboardItem pie = new PieDashboardItem();
        pie.DataSource = dashboard.DataSources[0];
        pie.Arguments.Add(new Dimension("Russia"));
        pie.Values.Add(new Measure("Open"));
        pie.Values.Add(new Measure("Closed"));


        dashboard.Items.Add(pie);
        //pieDashboardItem1.Dashboard = dashboard;

    }

    private void Dashboard1_DataLoading(object sender, DashboardDataLoadingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Data = new suggestReport().GetData();
    }

   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it's working by doing following.

```
      namespace IDBOWeb.Code.Dashboards
 {
public partial class Dashboard1 : DevExpress.DashboardCommon.Dashboard
{
public Dashboard1()
{
    InitializeComponent();


}

private void Dashboard1_DataLoading(object sender, DashboardDataLoadingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Data = GetUserSessionCount();   //use a private function returning a list of object
}
private List<DashBoardUserSessionDetails> GetUserSessionCount()
    {

        List<DashBoardUserSessionDetails> userList = proxy.GetUserSessionCounts();//get the listed object

        return userList;
    }

 }
}
```